# fdfind command need guidance, please?

Tags: linux, find, search

`find` command makes me go crazy!

Q1. Is there reason for me to still use it after i realized how easy fdfind command is ?

`$ fd find1 find2 ./folder`
Apparantly this fd command does not work as i like. It only find "find1" but not "find2".

Q2. How can i make it to find : find1 and find 2 both ? 
Q3. or make it to find either find1 or find2 ?
Q4. To exclude find1 or find2 ?

Thx

Comment: *Apparantly this fd command does not work as i like* Perhaps this answers your Q1. I am not sure what is the difference between Q2 and Q3; perhaps you can provide an example of your desired search? Also an example for Q4. I would exclude find2 by not mentioning it. To find files that are named *find1* or *find2*, try `fd '^find[12]$' ./folder` (this is from the tool's [Readme on Github](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd); I have not tried it).

Comment: To find things that are called `find1` or `find2` with `find`, you would use `find ./folder -name 'find[12]'`, or `find ./folder \( -name find1 -o -name find2 \)`.  Also, what's the actual difference between your 2nd and 3rd question?  In your last question, waht does "or" mean here? Does it mean "exclude either one but not both" or "exclude both"?

Comment: This question lacks one or several examples.

Answer (score 0):

I guess for that you have to resort to the classic `find` command:

```
find ./folder \( -name "find1" -o -name "find2" \)
```

Comment: `fd` uses regular expressions, and to search for find1 or find2, `fd '^find[12]$' ./folder` should work. Admittedly cleaner than the clumsy `find` syntax (although your example doesn't require parentheses).

Comment: That is neat. Works!

Comment: @berndbausch.. Wonderful! Thanks You saved my day.  I am glad this question of mine helped someone too :p)

Comment: @berndbausch Does that means i can totally forget about $find and just concentrate on learning $fd ?

Comment: I don't know if `fd` has all the features of `find`. Personally, I would not learn either. I read manpages when I have a need to accomplish something, not earlier.